# Logo image distorted in Chrome extension

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am developing a Chrome extension in React.js. The logo is specified in manifest.json:

```
    "icons": {
        "16": "images/logo.png",
        "48": "images/logo.png",
        "128": "images/logo.png"
    },
```

I have made a single logo.png and put it in dist/images:

[image]

This is how it shows in the extensions panel:

[image]

I cannot even see a similarity between the two images. What is going on and how do I fix it?

Comment: `icons` is for chrome://extensions page. You need to set `default_icon` inside `action`.

Comment: @wOxxOm It does not show in the extensions page either. The change did not do it. "action": {
        "default_popup": "js/index.html",
        "default_title": "React Chrome Extension",
        "default_icon": "images/logo.png"
    }

Comment: 1) Don't forget to reload the extension. 2) Try saving the file in a different image editor or in an online converter.